# Native bash regexp [[ $f =~ "^[^\.]+$" ]] never matching

Tags: regex, linux, bash, loops

I'm currently trying to loop through all files in a certain directory using bash. If the file matches the following regular expression, it outputs the filename. If it doesn't, it outputs 'not' and then the filename. The regular expression is supposed to filter out any files that have a '.' in them.

```
for f in * ; do
    if [[ $f =~ "^[^\.]+$" ]]; then
        echo "$f"
    else
        echo "not $f"
    fi                                                                                                           
done
```

It correctly loops through all the files, but for a reason that has stumped me for quite a while, I cannot get it to only exclude files with a '.' in them. For example, in a directory with the following files:

```
bashrc
gitconfig
install.sh
README.md
vimrc
```

the output of the script is such:

```
not bashrc
not gitconfig
not install.sh
not README.md
not vimrc
```

I validated the regular expression [here](http://regexr.com/3bmh9). Any thoughts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't quote the right-hand side of your expression.

```
if [[ $f =~ ^[^.]+$ ]]; then
```

Quotes make the string a literal substring, rather than a regular expression.
For better portability across bash versions, put your regex in a variable (single-quoted, which will make the backslash literal):

```
re='^[.]+$'
if [[ $f =~ $re ]]; then
```

---

That said, you could do this with an extglob as well:

```
shopt -s extglob # enable extended globs
for f in +([!.]); do
  printf 'Matched %q\n' "$f"
done
```

...or with a general-purpose pattern match:

```
for f in *; do
    if [[ $f = *.* ]]; then
        printf '%q contains a dot\n' "$f"
    else
        printf '%q does not contain a dot\n' "$f"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I new it would be something simple like that.

Comment: I'd probably have gone with `[[ $f =~ \. ]]` and inverted the blocks if I had been writing this in the first place.

Comment: @EtanReisner, ...or `[[ $f = *.* ]]`.